Checking subclass against metaclass type
I have a set of plugins that inherit from a metaclass. the metaclasss is defined like so:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MetaReader(ABC):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
        ...
        

and the subclass like so:
from utils.MetaReader import MetaReader
    class ABF2Reader(MetaReader):
        ...

This works, as far as I can tell, and I can instantiate classes and use them as intended. However, at some points I need to load these classes as plugins without instantiating them, and when I do, I need to check their subclass against the proper metaclass to know what to do with them when loaded. And there, I get some weird results:
from utils.MetaReader import MetaReader
from plugins.datareaders.ABF2Reader import ABF2Reader

    print(type(reader)) #reader is an instance of ABF2Reader
    print(type(MetaReader)) #MetaReader is just the metaclass, not instantiated
    print(type(ABF2Reader)) #Just the subclass, not instantiated

prints:
<class 'plugins.datareaders.ABF2Reader.ABF2Reader'>
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>

The type for reader is what I expect: it's an instance of ABF2Reader. But the types for the other two are not.  type(MetaReader) is also fine, but I expect type(ABF2Reader) to give me <class 'MetaReader'>, not <class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
Clearly I am using metaclasses wrong. Can someone shed some light on where I am screwing this up?

This code is not defining any new metaclasses to startwith.
And the truth is that you probably don´t need custom metaclasses anyway - it would be possible to tell if you said what is your intention with the use of metaclasses. As it is, though, we just have a 2-class hierarchy that does nothing.
So, abc.ABC, from which you inherit is a class, not a metaclass, which makes its subclasses work with the abc.abstractmethod decorator, and allow other, unrelated classes, to be registered as virtual subclasses of themselves with the myclass.register method.
What happens is that abc.ABC itself uses a custom metaclass, the abc.ABCMeta class - and you don´t show any reason why you would want to customize it. Anyway, that is why type(MetaReader) outputs ABCMeta: its metaclass, which means, the class from which the class "MetaReader" is itself an instance, is abc.ABCMeta, through inheritance of abc.ABC.
To apply a custom metaclass to your own classes, you´d first have to create such a metaclass, by inheriting it from type, or, in this case, from abc.ABCMeta (which inherits from type). Then, upon declaring a class, the named argument metaclass=MyMetaClass  have to be used, along with the class bases:
class MetaReader(abc.ABCMeta):
    # body which actually makes something useful on class
    # creation time, or the class behavior itself,
    # and which can´t be done by __init_subclass__
    # (usually by overriding __new__ or __call__ )    ...

class ABF2Reader(abc.ABC, metaclass=MetaReader):
    ...

Comlementing: after interacting with the O.P. in the comments - what they need is a way to find the superclass of the classes, not the metaclasses. The most usual way of checking that is with the issubclass call - metaclasses are not involved as described above. Onee may also want to inspect the class' __bases__ and __mro__ attributes at runtime.

I am using metaclasses here as a way to enforce proper interface implementation when other uses of the software implement plugins to modify local behaviors while still allowing integration with a larger code base. It would be possible to do this just through inheritance without metaclasses in principle, here I use them to ensure that the right methods are subclassed, etc.

correction: you are not using metaclasses there. Maybe you mean using "abstract classes" ?  Abstract base classes (abc) use a custom metaclass, but it is "ABCMeta"  - there is no need to customize anything in it to make use of abstract classes and the @abstractmethod decorator do enforce interfaces.

You are correct, I meant abstract classes - new set of terminology for me

So that is it - you don´t have to worry about datacasses, and what is printed by type(ABF2Reader) - just inherit from abc.ABC and use @abstractmethod as you see fit.

But the issue is that I have several abstract classes, and several subclasses of each, and I need to sort them at runtime based on the abstract class from which they inherit - which is difficult if type(subclass) is ABCmeta independent of the actual abstract class from which they inherit. It seems issubclass() is the way to go rather than type checking.

AH - you can achieve that with  subclass.__bases__[0]. Their type will always be abc.ABCMeta, __bases__ will have the explicit given immediate superclasses - and __mro__ , if you need it, the returns a tuple with the full linearized inheritance chain up to  object (if you need to get to the "GrandParent" classes as well).

but yes, the most usual check in cases like this is with issubclass
